# Grab image source from background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a div that looks like this:

```
" data-bg="url('//ichef.bbci.co.uk/onesport/cps/480/cpsprodpb/8A46/production/_110589353_19795035.jpg')" 
style="background-color: rgb(254, 212, 78);
 background-image: url(&quot;//ichef.bbci.co.uk/onesport/cps/480/cpsprodpb/8A46/production/_110589353_19795035.jpg&quot;);
" data-was-processed="true">
```

I'm trying to save that data-bg value in var image and eventually assigning to another img class.

I've tried something like:

```
.find('.lc-section-publisher img')
.attr('data-bg').replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "")
```

I've tried playing with it but it doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you change the last replace token to `.replace(/\'/gi, "")` it should work, since you are using `'' and not `"`' in the `data-bg` attribute value. Alternatively you can use this regex pattern instead: `^url\('(.*?)'\)$`

Comment: You could even do without the last `.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const url = "url('//ichef.bbci.co.uk/onesport/cps/480/cpsprodpb/8A46/production/_110589353_19795035.jpg')"
const matches = url.match(/\('(.+)'\)/)

console.log(matches && matches[1])
```